# Telegram Bot Api: how to get user count who joined by invite link

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I create multiple invite links to a private channel in Telegram using the Telegram Bot API. My question is, how can I count the number of users who joined the channel through a specific link using the Bot API? The bot is an administrator of the channel with all necessary permissions. When users join the channel, nothing is sent to the bot's webhook.

The answer should use the Telegram Bot API, but if you provide a complete code example, it can also use the Telegram API (I don't understand how to work with it) if it is applicable in this situation.

How I have created links:

```
$params = [
    'chat_id' => '-100*********'
];

$ch = curl_init($TgAPI.'bot'.'token'.'/createChatInviteLink');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    => 60
));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

print $output;
```

This is how I am trying get users count:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Load telegram-bot/api

$apiToken = 'hash';
$inviteLink = 'link';
$chatId     = '-100*****';

$telegram = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client($apiToken);

$importers = $telegram->messages->getChatInviteImporters($chatId, $inviteLink);

print_r($importers);
```

Above code gives error:
Fri Jul 14 07:33:40.260995 2023] [php7:error] [pid 698972] [client 127.0.0.1:45142] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getChatInviteImporters() on null in /home/leonid/Web/telegram/testMethod.php:36\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /home/leonid/Web/telegram/testMethod.php on line 36

**Update: I have written as answer using "Telegram Bot Api", however still looking for code using "Telegram Api" method getChatInviteImporters.**

Comment: Not sure if that is possible. Neither the Bot API `User` type, https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types, not the Telegram API `user`, https://core.telegram.org/constructor/user, show any fields that could be used to get this kind of information, as far as I can see.

Comment: @CBroe There are a type https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmemberupdated but telegram do not send it to webhook

Comment: And do you have your webhook properly configured to receive this type of update? Your `allowed_updates` setting will need to include `chat_member`. And explicit polling via [`getUpdates`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) is also an option they offer.

Comment: @CBroe webhook write log on all input, and I do not see any input. How to set this: "Your allowed_updates setting will need to include chat_member." ?

Comment: You need to specify it when you set up your webhook - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook It even explicitly says there, _"Specify an empty list to receive all update types except chat_member (default)."_ - so if you did not specify anything yet, then the update type you are interested in here, is the only one you will _not_ be getting.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I will try now. You can write an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

The webhook did not receive data about entering/leaving the channel. By default, the webhook setup is created without the chat_member rule.
I fixed it and it became possible to count users who came through a certain invite link. The invite link is included in the data sent to the webhook, but the link must be created by a same bot. If the link was created by another administrator (for example, another bot admin), then the invite link comes truncated, just at the end of the link, instead of the key, "..." is substituted

Here is an example code - setting all webhook subscriptions:

```php
function setWebhook($token) {
  global $TgAPI,$HOST;
  
  $url = $HOST."webhook.php?token=".$token;
  
  $POST = [
      'url'             => $url,
      'max_connections' => 10,
      'allowed_updates' => json_encode(['message','edited_message','channel_post','edited_channel_post','inline_query','chosen_inline_result','callback_query','shipping_query','pre_checkout_query','poll','poll_answer','my_chat_member','chat_member','chat_join_request'])
  ];
  
  $ch = curl_init($TgAPI.'bot'.$token.'/setWebhook');
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $POST,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT    => 60
  ));
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($ch);

  return [
    'code'   => $httpcode,
    'output' => json_decode($output,true)
  ];
  
}
```

Here is the example of chat_member object send to webhook when somebody joins:

```json
{
  "update_id": 1234567890,
  "chat_member": {
    "chat": {
      "id": -1001234567890,
      "title": "Test",
      "type": "channel"
    },
    "from": {
      "id": 1234567890,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "Test",
      "last_name": "Test"
    },
    "date": 1689332573,
    "old_chat_member": {
      "user": {
        "id": 1234567890,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test"
      },
      "status": "left"
    },
    "new_chat_member": {
      "user": {
        "id": 1234567890,
        "is_bot": false,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test"
      },
      "status": "member"
    },
    "invite_link": {
      "invite_link": "https://t.me/+hash",
      "creator": {
        "id": 1234567890,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "TestBot",
        "username": "TestBot"
      },
      "creates_join_request": false,
      "is_primary": true,
      "is_revoked": false
    }
  }
}
```